# How to add custom properties to Vue modules and instances

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, server-side-rendering

When you inspect a Vue component that you have imported, you will get something like this:

```
import ClickB from 'ClickB.vue';
console.log(ClickB);
```

[image]

I have seen that `nuxt` adds a custom property there (called `_nuxt`), just like there is `_ssrRegister`. I have 2 questions:

1. How is it possible to add properties to the component?
2. Can you pass that property from the component to its instances?

Comment: Both of your questions are answered here ~ https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is simple. Just decorate `Vue` prototype like this to add instance method:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

// Adding an instance method
Vue.prototype.$someMethod = function (methodOptions) {
    // Your own logic...
}
```

As a good practice, this code should be in your `index.js` or `main.js` file. Taking it one step further, you should put this code inside **plugins** as explained in [Vue documentation for plugins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html).

Answer (score 5):

You can always just add them to your definition and to access them you would use $options instance property.
Ref: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options